# Workflow of the naive surface nets algorithm

Tags: javascript, geometry-surface, iosurface

I'm currently studying isosurface extraction algorithms. I found a [introduction](https://0fps.net/2012/07/12/smooth-voxel-terrain-part-2/) to it here with working *Javascript* code. I have to notice that I'm not a Javascript coder.  I'm mainly Java and F# however I was able to port the code to F#.

After all my problem currently is understanding the implementation of the surface nets algorithm works. (Link provided down below). It's made by the author of the blog / introduction.

197 lines (169 sloc)  6.38 KB from [here](https://github.com/mikolalysenko/mikolalysenko.github.com/blob/master/Isosurface/js/surfacenets.js)

```
// The MIT License (MIT)
//
// Copyright (c) 2012-2013 Mikola Lysenko
//
// Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
// of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
// in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
// to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
// copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
// furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
//
// The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
// all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
// 
// THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
// IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
// FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
// AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
// LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
// OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN
// THE SOFTWARE.

/**
 * SurfaceNets in JavaScript
 *
 * Written by Mikola Lysenko (C) 2012
 *
 * MIT License
 *
 * Based on: S.F. Gibson, "Constrained Elastic Surface Nets". (1998) MERL Tech Report.
 */
var SurfaceNets = (function() {
"use strict";

//Precompute edge table, like Paul Bourke does.
// This saves a bit of time when computing the centroid of each boundary cell
var cube_edges = new Int32Array(24)
  , edge_table = new Int32Array(256);
(function() {

  //Initialize the cube_edges table
  // This is just the vertex number of each cube
  var k = 0;
  for(var i=0; i<8; ++i) {
    for(var j=1; j<=4; j<<=1) {
      var p = i^j;
      if(i <= p) {
        cube_edges[k++] = i;
        cube_edges[k++] = p;
      }
    }
  }

  //Initialize the intersection table.
  //  This is a 2^(cube configuration) ->  2^(edge configuration) map
  //  There is one entry for each possible cube configuration, and the output is a 12-bit vector enumerating all edges crossing the 0-level.
  for(var i=0; i<256; ++i) {
    var em = 0;
    for(var j=0; j<24; j+=2) {
      var a = !!(i & (1<<cube_edges[j]))
        , b = !!(i & (1<<cube_edges[j+1]));
      em |= a !== b ? (1 << (j >> 1)) : 0;
    }
    edge_table[i] = em;
  }
})();

//Internal buffer, this may get resized at run time
var buffer = new Int32Array(4096);

return function(data, dims) {

  var vertices = []
    , faces = []
    , n = 0
    , x = new Int32Array(3)
    , R = new Int32Array([1, (dims[0]+1), (dims[0]+1)*(dims[1]+1)])
    , grid = new Float32Array(8)
    , buf_no = 1;

  //Resize buffer if necessary 
  if(R[2] * 2 > buffer.length) {
    buffer = new Int32Array(R[2] * 2);
  }

  //March over the voxel grid
  for(x[2]=0; x[2]<dims[2]-1; ++x[2], n+=dims[0], buf_no ^= 1, R[2]=-R[2]) {

    //m is the pointer into the buffer we are going to use.  
    //This is slightly obtuse because javascript does not have good support for packed data structures, so we must use typed arrays :(
    //The contents of the buffer will be the indices of the vertices on the previous x/y slice of the volume
    var m = 1 + (dims[0]+1) * (1 + buf_no * (dims[1]+1));

    for(x[1]=0; x[1]<dims[1]-1; ++x[1], ++n, m+=2)
    for(x[0]=0; x[0]<dims[0]-1; ++x[0], ++n, ++m) {

      //Read in 8 field values around this vertex and store them in an array
      //Also calculate 8-bit mask, like in marching cubes, so we can speed up sign checks later
      var mask = 0, g = 0, idx = n;
      for(var k=0; k<2; ++k, idx += dims[0]*(dims[1]-2))
      for(var j=0; j<2; ++j, idx += dims[0]-2)      
      for(var i=0; i<2; ++i, ++g, ++idx) {
        var p = data[idx];
        grid[g] = p;
        mask |= (p < 0) ? (1<<g) : 0;
      }

      //Check for early termination if cell does not intersect boundary
      if(mask === 0 || mask === 0xff) {
        continue;
      }

      //Sum up edge intersections
      var edge_mask = edge_table[mask]
        , v = [0.0,0.0,0.0]
        , e_count = 0;

      //For every edge of the cube...
      for(var i=0; i<12; ++i) {

        //Use edge mask to check if it is crossed
        if(!(edge_mask & (1<<i))) {
          continue;
        }

        //If it did, increment number of edge crossings
        ++e_count;

        //Now find the point of intersection
        var e0 = cube_edges[ i<<1 ]       //Unpack vertices
          , e1 = cube_edges[(i<<1)+1]
          , g0 = grid[e0]                 //Unpack grid values
          , g1 = grid[e1]
          , t  = g0 - g1;                 //Compute point of intersection
        if(Math.abs(t) > 1e-6) {
          t = g0 / t;
        } else {
          continue;
        }

        //Interpolate vertices and add up intersections (this can be done without multiplying)
        for(var j=0, k=1; j<3; ++j, k<<=1) {
          var a = e0 & k
            , b = e1 & k;
          if(a !== b) {
            v[j] += a ? 1.0 - t : t;
          } else {
            v[j] += a ? 1.0 : 0;
          }
        }
      }

      //Now we just average the edge intersections and add them to coordinate
      var s = 1.0 / e_count;
      for(var i=0; i<3; ++i) {
        v[i] = x[i] + s * v[i];
      }

      //Add vertex to buffer, store pointer to vertex index in buffer
      buffer[m] = vertices.length;
      vertices.push(v);

      //Now we need to add faces together, to do this we just loop over 3 basis components
      for(var i=0; i<3; ++i) {
        //The first three entries of the edge_mask count the crossings along the edge
        if(!(edge_mask & (1<<i)) ) {
          continue;
        }

        // i = axes we are point along.  iu, iv = orthogonal axes
        var iu = (i+1)%3
          , iv = (i+2)%3;

        //If we are on a boundary, skip it
        if(x[iu] === 0 || x[iv] === 0) {
          continue;
        }

        //Otherwise, look up adjacent edges in buffer
        var du = R[iu]
          , dv = R[iv];

        //Remember to flip orientation depending on the sign of the corner.
        if(mask & 1) {
          faces.push([buffer[m], buffer[m-du], buffer[m-du-dv], buffer[m-dv]]);
        } else {
          faces.push([buffer[m], buffer[m-dv], buffer[m-du-dv], buffer[m-du]]);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  //All done!  Return the result
  return { vertices: vertices, faces: faces };
};
})();
```

**I'll write here what I do understand and what is unclear to me:**

How I understand the algorithm:

1. Making a cube_edges (or rather vertex list) combination list and an edge list (look up tables)
2. Iterating through the complete grid with interpolating the float values of each vertex in the current cell/cube according their topology (relying on the edge list).
3. Pushing back the vertices and setting the faces.

What's unclear to me:

1. I already searched the Internet for the algorithm which generates the edges_table but I haven't found one. Is someone able to explain it to me?
2. How are the faces connected to each other. What happens in the last snippet where the faces made?

I'm open to improve my question to fit the rules.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't read the code you quote, but to answer your questions:

1. Edges_table algorithm is pretty simple, it follows a convention of mapping vertices and edges of a cube to a specific number. See [Paul Bourke's Implementation](http://paulbourke.net/geometry/polygonise/) for details.
2. In matching box algorithm, the point of intersection is usually calculated by linear interpolation of each vertex value:

> P = P1 + (isovalue - V1) (P2 - P1) / (V2 - V1)

Shared edges of adjacent cubes will always have the intersection point in the same position, so generated faces of adjacent cubes will always fit perfectly.